# Android - can not get JSON from PHP

Tags: php, android

```
  private void getJSON(String url) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Log.d(TAG, "onpre");
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait...", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                Log.d(TAG,"doin");
                String uri = params[0];

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);  Log.d(TAG, "url "+url);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(json+"\n");Log.d(TAG, "sb "+sb.toString());
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                 }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, " error");
                return null;
            }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
             Log.d(TAG,"json= "+s);
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(url);
    }
```

As you can see here
http://oep.esy.es/android_get_all.php

```
{"teachers":[{"tid":"1","name":"g\u00f6ksel","surname":"biricik",,"tc":"12345678912","email":"goksel@ce.yildiz.edu.tr","avatar":"goksel.jpg"},{"tid":"2","name":"haydar","surname":"ayg\u00f6rmez",,"tc":"12345678913","email":"aygormez@gmail.com","avatar":"haydar.jpg"},{"tid":"48","name":"Caner","surname":"Ayd\u0131n",,"tc":"12345678914","email":"caneraydinbey@gmail.com","avatar":"caner.jpg"},{"tid":"92","name":"deneme","surname":"denemesoy",","tc":"12345678914","email":"deneme@gmail.com","avatar":"5292-1017.png"},{"tid":"93","name":"deneme2","surname":"denemesoy2",,"tc":"12345678915","email":"deneme2@gmail.com","avatar":"8446-1012.png"}],"success":1}
```

I need to get data from here. But when i do this, i get null:

```
04-04 15:41:24.022 2131-2131/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: oncreate start
04-04 15:41:24.372 2131-2131/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: oncreate end
04-04 15:41:27.115 2131-2131/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: onpre
04-04 15:41:27.255 2131-2302/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: doin
04-04 15:41:27.485 2131-2131/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: json= null
04-04 15:44:19.623 5732-5732/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: oncreate start
04-04 15:44:19.753 5732-5732/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: oncreate end
04-04 15:46:26.537 5732-5732/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: onpre
04-04 15:46:26.697 5732-8187/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: doin
04-04 15:46:26.697 5732-8187/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: url http://oep.esy.es/android_get_all.php
04-04 15:46:26.867 5732-5732/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication D/Chic: json= null
```

Why do i get null? There is no warning or errors. omly this:

```
04-04 15:54:00.990 5732-5732/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

I did same implements as here

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-tutorial-to-get-data-from-mysql-database/

Comment: always keep habit of printing `Exception` in `catch` block, check whether you are getting any `Exception`

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace();` inside catch block and edit your post. It'll be helpful for you and for us.

Comment: How to search where prinstack posted? I search all logs to find "exception"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works

```js
   return String.valueOf(sb);
```